# How to group Postgres data correctly

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

In PostgreSQL, I have such table:

```
| QUESTION_TEXT                          | CATEGORY | AGREE_PERCENT | DISAGREE_PERCENT |
|----------------------------------------|----------|---------------|------------------|
| Do you support the President's policy? | Policy   | 50            | 50               |
| Do you support Democrats?              | Policy   | 32            | 68               |
| Do you support the Lannisters?         | Cinema   | 45            | 55               |
| Do you support Spielberg's work?       | Cinema   | 60            | 40               |
```

In my Go application with the help of [gorm library](http://gorm.io/) I make SQL request to PostgreSQL database like that:

```
type Entry struct {
     QuestionText string `json:"question_text"`
     Category string `json:"category"`
     AgreePercent float64 `json:"agree_percent"`
     DisagreePercent float64 `json:"disagree_percent"`
}

rows, _ := database.DBGORM.Raw("SELECT * FROM SPECIFICATION").Rows()

for rows.Next() {
     entry := &Entry{}

     if err = rows.Scan(&entry.QuestionText, & entry.Category,  &entry.AgreePercent, &entry.DisagreePercent); err != nil {
          utils.Logger().Println(err)   
     }
}
```

How to get a similar result? As you can see each object inside the array is grouped by value in the `category` column:

```
[
     {
          category: "Policy",
          questions: ["Do you support the President's policy?", "Do you support Democrats?"],
          series: [
               {
                    name: "Agree, %",
                    data: [50, 32]
               },
               {
                    name: "Disagree, %",
                    data: [50, 68]
               },
          ] 
     },
     {
          category: "Cinema",
          questions: ["Do you support the Lannisters?", "Do you support Spielberg's work?"],
          series: [
               {
                    name: "Agree, %",
                    data: [45, 60]
               },
               {
                    name: "Disagree, %",
                    data: [55, 40]
               },
          ] 
     },
]
```

Comment: Is the last snippet what you *want* to get or what you *actually* get?

Comment: "How to get a similar result?" – similar *to what*?

Comment: You don't show where this output gets generated from, so it's really hard to know what does the grouping. My guess is that there is some logic doing the grouping later on, and the grouped output is printed. If you print out each scanned line as you read it from the DB, you should see a raw approximation of the pg table

Comment: @EliBendersky at the moment there is no grouping. I want output as in the example above. Do you have any ideas how I can make it?

Comment: @mkrieger1 hello! In the end of the post you can notice JSON output which I want to generate in my golang application. How to get this kind of result? Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I can't say that it's elegant way, but finally I solve my task:

```
// Create struct called "Series".
type Series struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Data []float64 `json:"data"`
}

// Create struct called "Specification".
type Specification struct {
    Category string `json:"category"`
    Questions []string `json:"questions"`
    Series []Series `json:"series"`
}

// Initialize an array of struct.
var specifications []Specification

// Initialize several variables.
var catogoryName string
var arrayQuestionText []string
var arrayAgreePercent []float64
var arrayDisagreePercent []float64


for rows.Next() {
    // Check the change in the name of the category.
    if entry.Category == catogoryName {
        // Add new elements to arrays.
        arrayQuestionText = append(arrayQuestionText, entry.QuestionText)
        arrayDisagreePercent = append(arrayDisagreePercent, entry.DisagreePercent)
        arrayAgreePercent = append(arrayAgreePercent, entry.AgreePercent)
    } else {
        if len(catogoryName) > 0 {
            // Fill the struct with data.
            specification := Specification{
                Category: catogoryName,
                Questions: arrayQuestionText,
                Series: []Series{
                    {
                        Name: "Agree, %",
                        Data: arrayAgreePercent,
                    },
                    {
                        Name: "Disagree, %",
                        Data: arrayDisagreePercent,
                    },
                },
            }

            // Add new struct to array.
            specifications = append(specifications, specification)
        }
    }
    // Update data in arrays.
    catogoryName = entry.Category
    arrayQuestionText = nil
    arrayQuestionText = append(arrayQuestionText, entry.QuestionText)
    arrayDisagreePercent = nil
    arrayDisagreePercent = append(arrayDisagreePercent, entry.DisagreePercent)
    arrayAgreePercent = nil
    arrayAgreePercent = append(arrayAgreePercent, entry.AgreePercent)
}
```